# CodeIgniter PHP MySQL Query to View

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, variables

**I'm missing something here, I can't get variables to pass through the model to the view via controller.**

**I'm recieving:** *The website encountered an error while retrieving site. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.* **currently.**

**If I remove the 2nd** *$this->load->model('testingsearch');* **then I get the following error message:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: HW::$testingsearch
>
> Filename: controllers/hw.php
>
> Line Number: 63

**MODEL:**

```
<?php

class TestingSearch extends Model
{
function Messages()
{
    parent::Model();
}

function getMessages($id)
{
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $result = $this->db->get('HWC');

    if (!$result) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $result;
        echo $result;
    }
}
}
?>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
<?php

class HW extends CI_Controller {

function Thiscontroller()
{
  parent::Controller();
  $this->load->database(); // This should be autoloaded

  $this->load->model('testingsearch');
}


function id($id='') {
       $this->load->model('testingsearch');
         $data['records'] = $this->testingsearch->getMessages($id);

   $this->load->view('searchresults', $data);

}

}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($records->result() as $row) { ?>
<li><?php echo $row->id; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $row->ModelName; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $row->Color; ?></li>
<? } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Comment the echo $result; after return; step and print_r($result) from model and see what you get there.

Comment: Shouldn't `extends Model` be `extends CI_Model`?

Comment: @Nish no change... cryptic  nice catch, yes but still no change on the results

Comment: `$this->load->model('testingSearch');` please check the code for loading model.

Comment: your model should extend to CORE of CI_MODEL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Please make change in ::::::

MODEL code:

```
function getMessages($id)
{
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $result = $this->db->get('HWC');

    return $result->result();
}
```

VIEW code:-

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($records as $row) { ?>
<li><?php echo $row->id; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $row->ModelName; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $row->Color; ?></li>
<? } ?>
</ul>
```

It will solve your problem.................

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending anything to controller. Only you are sending indicator whethere model function returning true or false. return the object

MODEL:

```
Class TestingSearch extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getMessages($id)
    {
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $result = $this->db->get('HWC');

        return $result->result();
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
class HW extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->database(); // This should be autoloaded

      $this->load->model('testingsearch');
    }

    function id($id='') 
    {
        $this->load->model('testingsearch');
        $data['records'] = $this->testingsearch->getMessages($id);
        $this->load->view('searchresults', $data);
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($records->result() as $row) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $row->id; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $row->ModelName; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $row->Color; ?></li>
    <? } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong extension of your MODEL

```
 // model should extend CI_Model
    class TestingSearch extends CI_Model{
        // then add additional constructor to call the model
        function __construct(){
              paret::__construct();
        }
    }


 // in controller
class HW extends CI_Controller {
 // change your call to the constructor by using
 function HW(){
     parent::CI_Controller()
     // then load the model
     $this->load->model('testingsearch');
  }
 }
```